# ayuda con jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

tengo el siguiente problema:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div id="slides" id="banner">
        <img class="slide active" src="img/slide1.png">
        <img class="slide" src="img/slide1.png">
        <img class="slide" src="img/slide1.png">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="banner-prev" class="flecha-banner anterior"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a href="#" id="banner-next" class="flecha-banner siguiente"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

y en un js tengo esto:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var banner = {
    padre: $('#banner'),
    numeroSlides : $('#banner').children('.slide').length
  }
  console.log(banner.numeroSlides);
});
```

al depurar en el console log, tengo como resultado 0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no tiene sentido, por que le estoy diciendo quiero todos los hijos del elemento #banner con la clase .slide, y que me calcule el numero.

si me ayudan se los agradeceria.. gracias de antemano

tengo la ultima version de jquery 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día. Al parecer tu código en Javascript está correcto. El único error que tienes es que has colocado dos propiedad ID al div contenedor:

```
<div id="slides" id="banner">
```

Eso es incorrecto, por favor borra `id="slides"` y deberia funcionar. Saludos

Comment: rayos, nose como no lo vi, muchas gracias!!!